# Watin - how to ctrl-click a link?

Tags: click, watin, browser-automation

It seems like a simple operation - given a Watin Link class, how do you perform a crtl-click on the link?  I don't see how you can perform a keyDown for ctrl using either a Watin method or System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is control clicking even a supported mode of mouse usage on windows?

On the Mac it is the equivalent of "right clicking", so do you just need to click with the other button ?

Comment: It is possible to check for any combination of ctrl, shift, and alt keys pressed during a mouseclick (either right or left button) with javascript, so I'm looking for a way to generate those events.  I'm not mac-savvy, but because there is also right-clicking on the PC, I would think ctrl would map to a similar key on the mac keyboard.